# Can't rotate (Default) screen on Raspberry Pi3 running Manjaro with X11

Tags: raspberry-pi, rotation, x11, xorg, archlinux-arm

I’m running the latest version of Manjaro ARM i3 on a Raspberry Pi3 (Image: Raspberry Pi 4 I3 20.10). I can’t for the love of me get the screen to rotate. I recently switched from Manjaro Wayland to this version because of Synergy support.

What I tried:

- Using `xrandr` to rotate the screen. xrandr only sees a “Default” screen and when I try to rotate it I get the error:

  ```
  $ xrandr --output default --rotate inverted
  xrandr: output default cannot use rotation "inverted" reflection "none"
  ```
- Using `ARandR` to rotate the screen. This will show my desktop in the GUI tool but the options to Rotate are greyed out. My main screen shows up as 'Default' here to.
- Using the Raspberry PI config file at `/boot/config.txt` to set the rotation. This does also not work.

I’m running the Stock version with no extra software. Any tips on how to get the screen to rotate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found a even better solution thanks to the user [BashCrash over at the Manjaro Forum](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/i3-on-raspberry-pi-4-with-dual-monitors/20996/7?u=bofarm)

The steps are as followed (with `vc4-fkms-v3d` enabled in the `/boot/config.txt`):

- Boot into Manjaro i3
- Open a terminal
- Go to to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` (`cd /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`)
- Move the file `99-fbturbo.conf.d` with `mv 99-fbturbo.conf.d 99-fbturbo.conf.d.old`
- Reboot

After the reboot you `xrandr` should list the correct outputs (`HDMI-1` in my case). You can then rotate the screen using:

```sh
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --rotate left
```

You can make this setting permanent by adding it to you `.i3/config` file. Add the following line:

```sh
exec xrandr --output HDMI-1 --rotate left
```

The trade off with the original method is that the screen will rotate after boot and login. More in depth explanation on potential trade-off's can be found here: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/i3-on-raspberry-pi-4-with-dual-monitors/20996/9

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this by disabling the `vc4-fkms-v3d` drivers. You can do this using the following steps:

1. Open you config file at `/boot/config.txt`
2. Using a `#`, comment out the line: `vc4-fkms-v3d`
3. Add the rotation to the config like:

- `display_rotate=1` - for 90 degree rotation
- `display_rotate=2` - for 180 degree rotation
- `display_rotate=3` - for 270 degree rotation

4. Reboot

Your screen should now be rotated. Please note that this disables the `vc4-fkms-v3d` video card drivers which could have other unforeseen effects. Also keep in mind that this is the case for a RPi3.